# Secure access of webassets with Flask and AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

I am trying to serve files securely (images in this case) to my users. I would like to do this using flask and preferably amazon s3 however I would be open to another cloud storage solution if required.

I have managed to get my flask static files like css and such on s3 however this is all non-secure. So everyone who has the link can open the static files. This is obviously not what I want for secure content. I can't seems to figure out how I can make a file available to just authenticated user that 'owns' the file.

For example: When I log into my dropbox account and copy a random file's download link. Then go over to anther computer and use this link it will denie me access. Even though I am still logged in and the download link is available to user on the latter pc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secured RESTful API that can be used by Web App (angular), iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400476/secured-restful-api-that-can-be-used-by-web-app-angular-ios-and-android)

Answer (score 1):

Make the request to your Flask application, which will authenticate the user and then issue a redirect to the S3 object. The trick is that the redirect should be to a signed temporary URL that expires in a minute or so, so it can't be saved and used later or by others.

You can use `boto.s3.key.generate_url` function in your Flask app to create the temporary URL.

Comment: I can indeed do that but the link will be available to all users. I could add some obscure number to the request but if someone would intercept the link they would still have full access to it even when the user would have logged off.

Comment: No, they couldn't. The link would no longer work after it expired, which could be as little as one minute after you created it. Take a look at Amazon's description of it at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth .

Comment: This is the right answer. Yes, it is still accessible to anyone with the link (during the time defined). You can proxy S3 data through your server, but you lose any S3 advantage doing it.

Comment: @irisilvio I think that for images that are semi private the latter is a good solution. However for personal documents I would prefer another layer of security. How would I as you mentioned proxy data through my server?